Do analog computers exist?
Given the current state of physics and quantum mechanics is it possible theoretically to build an analog computer that, for example, calculates the addition of two real numbers? Where theoretically if we had an infinite amount of time we can verify correctness?

Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer?

@Fe2O3 due to planck length that's impossible. Do you have any knowledge of quantum mechanics?

@Bergi No, what's wikipedia? Never heard of it.

@Fe2O3 I don't understand your solution there

@JobHunter69 If sarcasm (and you read the article), please edit the title of your question to fit better to what you actually want to know. If not, you're one of today's lucky ten thousand :-)

@Bergi I think its pretty clear. The world is not continuous, it's discrete. So analog computers cannot exist

@JobHunter69 That was not clear, please [edit] that argument into the question. Maybe add a "true" in the title. You seem to use an unconventional definition of "analog". Nobody needs infinite precision, or cares about quantisation of values that are way below the measurement error.

A common misconception is "quantum means discrete", often due to the etymology. Quantum mechanics assume space is continuous, and Schrodinger's equation even has differentiation in it.

There are undoubtedly machines that meet the criteria of an "analog computer" which are capable of addition.
Pouring two jugs of water together is essentially an analog computation of addition - if the purpose of the activity is to read off the information about the combined volume in the final container.
The physical nature of computation is not different from the physical nature of the natural world in the course of its ordinary motion. What makes it "computation" is the purpose for which a specific physical process is made to occur by human effort - so the difference between mixing the ingredients of a cake and "computation", is only the purpose for which it is done.
It's for this reason that some have characterised the universe as a big computer - although I would put it the other way around, that a big enough computer (which is a man-made device) would be indistinguishable from the universe (which is not man-made).
And all digital computers are ultimately built from analog components, so there can be nothing in theory which an analog computer cannot handle.
From a mechanical perspective, digital computers are assemblages of small analog components performing very rudimentary computations. What makes them digital is that the continuously-variable physical states of each analog component are constantly renormalised at each stage of processing into exclusive ranges which represent discrete states.
The reason this is done is because multi-stage analog computations accumulate error relentlessly, and are very sensitive to the physical conditions of the machine.
This makes it very difficult to design analog computers that are both complicated to a useful degree, and precise.
Analog computers which do more than the most trivial computation but maintain the continuously-variable principle from end-to-end, typically need enormously precise manufacturing of hardware, and also need complicated analog regulatory mechanisms built into them which stabilise internal signals against variations in the physical condition of the machine which are considered spurious influences on the output.

This is a good answer, I'd only add that, analog computers really are still everywhere.
A modern digital thermometer for example, still needs some analog component to measure the temperature of the room. It'd work by having some electronic resistor that's specifically made to increase resistance in precise values, whenever the temperature in the air increases.
That analog resistance value, then needs to be converted using an Analog To Digital Converter.
One idea to distinguish too is that Electronic does not mean Digital. An electronic calculator can be Analog or Digital.

None of that is analog due to quantum mechanics

@JobHunter69 Well if it comes to that, "digital" computers are made from analog transistors.

@Pseudonym Aren't they also technically discrete due to quantum mechanics?

@JobHunter69 Continuous-variable quantum systems say hi.

@JobHunter69 Think of it this way, if it helps. Electric charge is quantised because it's always a whole number of electrons. Electric current, charge per unit time, is not quantised because time is not quantised.

@Kiro I was unaware of that. given the existence of that analog computers are possible.

@Pseudonym yeah, so my question is how do you use a ratio of something per time to build out an analog computer?

@Pseudonym to say that digital computers are analog because transistors are analog doesn't make sense because the number is still represented discretely

As part of an undergrad course in the 1970s i built an analog computer on a breadboard to simulate the ODE describing water hammer. From memory it was a RLC circuit. The circuit parameters were derived using the analogy between Mechanical & Electrical engineering values ( eg potential/voltage is pressure I believe).
So analog computers can be built, but now I see a new type of analog computers are becoming available in which I believe  circuit parameters (capacitance, resistance etc)  are set digitally.
The reason behind this is that for decades the governing equations of physical systems have been digitised in order to solve them but now it is possible to produce easy to use analog computers. Analog ODEs are better solved without the need to approximate naturally analog systems digitally.
